# Matrix "Move to top/bottom" feature erases content from Wygwam Field

Tags: matrix, wygwam

EE 2.5.3, Matrix 2.5.2, Wygwam 2.6.3

---

When a Wygwam cell is part of a Matrix and that row is dragged and dropped into a new order, everything is fine.

However, if you use the "Move to top" (or bottom) feature from the cell options dialog, the field moves and the Wygwam content is cleared.

[image: dialog]

Before moving:
[image: before]

After moving:
[image]

Comment: This isn't really a question, it's more like a bug report... Should it be here?

Comment: Perhaps not, but I was going on the assumption that support moved here. "And as of today, we’re making EE Stack Exchange our primary support site." --

https://pixelandtonic.com/blog/ee-stack-exchange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was fixed in Matrix 2.5.3. http://pixelandtonic.com/matrix/releasenotes

Comment: Brandon, I just installed this and while the Move to Top and Move to Bottom features don't destroy content, they don't actually do anything either.

I get "Uncaught TypeError: [object Object] has no method 'callback' - matrix.js:147

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but there is a matrix.js file in the Wygwam folder that handles the drag events. I suppose its possible there is not an event for move to top/bottom, or no methods are bound to those events?

Comment: In matrix2.js I only see bindings for 'beforeSort' and 'afterSort'. In matrix's matrix.js I don't see any callbacks other than display, beforeSort, afterSort and remove.

I'm not good enough with JS to really tell what's going on.

Comment: I can reproduce this and will report it as a bug to our team.  I am sorry that you are encountering this. :(

Comment: Thanks for the update, Lisa. I'll just inform the users  to use drag and drop for reordering until this is resolved. Thanks!